# Token with multiple Scopes can only get access to single Scope/Api Resource

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, identityserver4

I have a Problem with Authenticating my Applications with IdentityServer4.

I have:

- a IdentityServer4-Server to authenticate multiple Clients
  (running on localhost:5000)
- a Api which is mainly used for storing and retrieving data
  with SignalR (running on localhost:5200)
- a Web-Application to read & write Data from the Api and have
  User specific interactions (running on localhost:80)
- and a Desktop-Application to read Data from Api

What works:

- Desktop User can use "ApiClient" to use Api with
  Client-Credential-Flow.
- Web User can use "WebClient" to get a Token with Implicit-Flow when
  Logging in.

What doesnt work:

- Web Client cant Authenticate on the Api using his Token from
  Implicit-Flow, even though he has the scope for the Api.

ApiResources:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis = new List<ApiResource>
{
    new ApiResource("WebApplicationResource", ""),
    new ApiResource("ApiServerResource", "")
};
```

Clients:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients = new List<Client>
{
    // Web Application (SPA) Client
    new Client
    {
        ClientId = "WebClient",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
        RequireConsent = false,
        RedirectUris = {
            "http://localhost:3000/callback"
        },
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = {
            "http://localhost:3000/post_logout"
        },
        AllowedCorsOrigins = {
            "http://localhost:3000"
        },
        AllowedScopes = {
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
            "WebApplicationResource",
            "WebApiResourceScope"
        }
    },
    // Api (Signalr) Client
    new Client
    {
        ClientId = "ApiClient",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
        RequireConsent = false,
        ClientSecrets = {
            new Secret("SecretCredentialsValue".Sha256())
        },
        AllowedScopes = {
            "WebApiResourceScope"
        }
    }
};
```

IS4 Server Authentication in Startup:

```
//in ConfigureServices
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", jwt =>
    {
        jwt.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        jwt.Audience = "WebApplicationResource";
        jwt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });
...
//in Configure
app.UseIdentityServer();
```

Api Server adding IS4 Authentication in Startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ApiName = "WebApiResourceScope";
    });
```

Api Server SignalR implementation in Startup:

```
//in ConfigureServices
services.AddSignalR()
...
//in Configure
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<EventHub>("/api");
    });
```

SignalR Hub Authentication added with:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
```

Here is the output when testing:

Api showing that Desktop Client can Authenticate:
[image: Api showing that Desktop Client could Authenticate]

The Web Client after successfully logging in, trying to authenticate on the SignalR Server which is on the Api (like the Client did on top) with its bearer token.
[image: Web Application not authenticating when accessing]

Console Output when Error happening:
[image: Console Output of Error]

Output of Api, showing that Bearer Token was not authenticated:
[image: Output of Api showing that authentication failed]

Did I misunderstood something about the scopes? Why can i add multiple scopes on Web Client but only use it on one of the declared Api Resources?

Do I have to get 2 Tokens for the Web Client? If so, what should i use to get a Token, Client Credentials isn't recommended on Web to Web communication.

Or what is it that I am not understanding.

Comment: One thing I'm not seeing here, so I need to ask - yes your WebClient is allowed to access the scope, but when logging in your user, are you requesting this scope? In other words (I see you are using userManager() class, I'm guessing oidc-client-js) - what are the user manager settings, that you are passing? When configuring the WebClient settings, are you specifying that you are requesting the scope you want?

Comment: In your mvc client make sure you have options.Scopes.Add(“your scope name”);

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 you are correct, I have used oidc-client in my Web Application with React, but i definetly did add all the same scopes as in the web client in IS4. I can't post the usermanager settings right now, sorry.

Comment: @SergSam - Just to be sure - I see that you are hitting the breakpoint `resolve(user.access_token)`, why don't you check the token in `https://jwt.io` and verify that your scope is there. You definitely don't need to get 2 access tokens, to access 2 api's, with your setup.

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 i had checked the Token on jwt.io, the scopes were included pretty sure. I just didnt know how to verify the signature (the blue part), so i dont know whats in there and what its for.

Comment: Just to cover all bases, your response_type is 'id_token token' correct?

Comment: I got it solved, not 100% sure what the problem was, but i had the order of the services added wrong and also added TokenRetriever to get the Token from the Querystring, probably one of these caused the problem. Thank you for clearing up my questions.